# Minimum value for x Axis doesn't work for horizontal bar chart | ChartJS

Tags: charts, bar-chart, chart.js, stacked-chart

I am using Chart.js (www.chartjs.org) to show the representation of the time spent on activities during the work. I have "Working"(green), "Smoking"(red), "At lunch"(orange), "At Toilette"(blue) and "At home"(grey) and I need to show all of them during a day for every worker. For that, I am using the horizontal bar stacked chart and it looks like this:

[Before setting the minimum value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CHAi.jpg) - x Axis represents hours (0-24)

It bothers me that a lot of space is used for "At home", but I want to see only the time from 7 to 18. I tried to set ticks min to 7 but it doesn't work, and after that it looks like this:

[After setting the minimum value to 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhxK7.jpg)

You can see that the graph is messed up and I don't know why. How can I achieve that the x Axis begins from 7, and data is still represented correctly?

Here is my code:

```
var updateMainChart = function(data) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "api/get_activitytracks.php?q=commands",
        success: function(response) {
            response = JSON.parse(response);
            if (response.statusCode == 200) {

                //get activity names
                var activities = $.map(response.data, function(n, i) {
                    return n.title;
                });

                //get max number of activities
                var names = [];
                var max = 0;
                Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key, index) {
                    names.push(key);
                });
                $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                    if (value.length > max) {
                        max = value.length;
                    }
                });

                //build datasets
                var myDataSets = [];
                var colors = [
                    'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.6)',
                    'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6)',
                    'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.6)',
                    'rgba(255, 127, 80, 0.6)',
                    'rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.8)'
                ];
                for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {

                    for (var j = 0; j < activities.length; j++) {
                        var obj = {};
                        obj["backgroundColor"] = Array.apply(null, Array(names.length))
                            .map(String.prototype.valueOf, colors[j]);
                        //obj[borderColor] = 'rgba(255,255,255,1)';
                        obj["borderWidth"] = 1;
                        obj["data"] = [];
                        obj["stack"] = "dummy";

                        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                            if (undefined !== value[i]) {
                                if (value[i]["title"] === activities[j]) {
                                    obj["data"].push(value[i]["duration"]);
                                } else {
                                    obj["data"].push(0);
                                }
                            } else {
                                obj["data"].push(0);
                            }
                        });
                        myDataSets.push(obj);
                    }
                }

                $("#statsChart").show();

                $("#mainChart").html("");
                $("#mainChart").append('<canvas id="statsChart" height="70%"></canvas>');

                var myBarChart = new Chart($("#statsChart"), {
                    type: 'horizontalBar',
                    data: {
                        labels: names,
                        datasets: myDataSets
                    },
                    options: {
                        scales: {
                            xAxes: [{
                                stacked: true,
                                ticks: {
                                    min: 7
                                }
                            }],

                            yAxes: [{
                                stacked: true
                            }]
                        },
                        legend: {
                            display: false
                        },
                        tooltips: {
                            callbacks: {
                                label: function(tooltipItem) {
                                    return tooltipItem.yLabel;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is a bug with the current Chart.js version.

As a workaround you could use a callback at the tick of you xAxes like this:

```
options: {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            stacked: true,
            ticks: {
                min: 0,
                callback: function(value, index, values) {
                    return value + 7;
                }
            }
        }],
    ...
```

For more details on callbacks have a look at the [documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales).

Comment: Sorry for my late comment. I've tried that and it has done the thing but my all values from the x Axe have been increased by 7. The values are crucial here because they represent the correct hour in a day 0-24H.

Answer (score 1):

```
options: {
  scales: {
      xAxes: [{
          display: true,
          ticks: {
              suggestedMin: 7
          }
      }]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**This will work for both Vertical and Horizontal**

```
options:{
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      ticks: {
          suggestedMin: 0,
          suggestedMax: 100
      }
    }],
    yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
          suggestedMin: 0,
          suggestedMax: 100
      }
    }],
  },
}
```